# Pandas group by several values in a single column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've created a pandas dataframe from a 205MB csv (approx 1.1 million rows by 15 columns). It holds a column called `starttime` that is dtype `object` (it's more precisely a string). The format is as follows: `7/1/2015 00:00:03`.

I would like to create two new dataframes from this pandas dataframe. One should contain all rows corresponding with weekend dates, the other should contain all rows corresponding with weekday dates.

Weekend dates are:

```
weekends = ['7/4/2015', '7/5/2015', '7/11/2015', '7/12/2015', 
            '7/18/2015', '7/19/2015', '7/25/2015', '7,26/2015']
```

I attempted to convert the string to datetime (`pd.to_datetime`) hoping that would make the values easier to parse, but when I do it hangs for so long that I ended up restarting the kernel several times.

Then I decided to use `df["date"], df["time"] = zip(*df['starttime'].str.split(' ').tolist())` to create two new columns in the original dataframe (one for date, one for time). Next I figured I'd use a boolean test to 'flag' weekend records (according to the new `date` field) as `True` and all others `False` and create another column holding those values, then I'd be able to group by `True` and `False`.

For example,
`test1 = bikes['date'] == '7/1/2015'` returns `True` for all 7/1/2015 values, but I can't figure out how to iterate over all items in `weekends` so that I get `True` for all weekend dates. I tried this and broke Python (hung again):

```
for i in weekends:
    for k in df['date']:
        test2 = df['date'] == i
```

I'd appreciate any help (with both my logic and my code).

Comment: You should be able to parse that string whilst reading in your csv so if you passed either the column name or the ordinal value to `read_csv` then it would read it in as a datetime fine: `pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['starttime'])` should work, then you can just call `df['starttime'].dt.dayofweek` and all weekends will be those with values in `[5,6]`

Comment: @EdChum thanks for your suggestion, but I'm receiving a `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` error. I think that's because `starttime` is a string.

Comment: You've not stated whether you have already tried to parse the string using `parse_dates` like I've said, you need to parse either during reading from csv of as a post-processing step which for some reason causes your computer to freeze which is shouldn't

Comment: @EdChum I followed your directions exactly and received that message.

Comment: @EdChum I missed the brackets. Your solution worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a DataFrame of string timestamps with 1.1m rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['7/1/2015 00:00:03', '7/1/2015 00:00:04'] * 550000})
```

Next, you can simply convert them to Pandas timestamps as follows:

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

This operation took just under two minutes.  However, it took under seven seconds if you specify the format:

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Now, it is easy to set up a weekend flag as follows (which took about 3 seconds):

```
df['weekend'] = [d.weekday() >= 5 for d in df.ts]
```

Finally, it is easy to subset your DataFrame, which takes virtually no time:

```
df_weekdays = df.loc[~df.weekend, :]
df_weekends = df.loc[df.weekend, :]
```

The weekend flag is to help explain what is happening.  You can simplify as follows:

```
df_weekdays = df.loc[df.ts.apply(lambda ts: ts.weekday() < 5), :]
df_weekends = df.loc[df.ts.apply(lambda ts: ts.weekday() >= 5), :]
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance. You're definitely right about it being super fast.